# AngularJS Modal Service Stops Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refactoring, angular-services

I've created a `modal` service within my Angular app that I can inject into controllers or directives. I'm running into a problem where after opening/closing a modal multiple times, everything within the modal stops workings. The modal works by grabbing content from a hidden div on the page and popping it into the modal. I've been able to determine that at some point, the value of `modal.settings` changes. If I insert a `debugger` at the beginning of my `modal.open` function and save the value of `var x = settings` in my console, I can see that after a few cycles, `x !== settings`. I've also tried comparing `modal.settings`, but the same thing happens. Eventually, after a few cycles, `modal.settings` changes and things stop working.

I think I need to refactor this service, but I'm not sure where to start and could use some guidance.

Here is the service code:

```
app.service('modal', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    var modal = this;
    modal.settings;
    modal.contents;
    modal.overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    modal.modal = $('<div id="modal"></div>');
    modal.content = $('<div id="content"></div>');
    modal.closeBtn = $('<div id="close"><i class="fa fa-times"></div>');

    modal.modal.hide();
    modal.overlay.hide();
    modal.modal.append(modal.content, modal.closeBtn);

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').append(modal.overlay, modal.modal);
    });

    modal.open = function (settings) {
        if(!modal.settings) {
            modal.settings = settings;
        }

        modal.content.empty().append(modal.settings.content);
        if(modal.settings.class) modal.modal.addClass(modal.settings.class);
        if(modal.settings.height) modal.modal.css({ height: modal.settings.height });
        if(modal.settings.width) modal.modal.css({ width: modal.settings.width });
        if(modal.settings.content_height) modal.modal.css({ height: modal.settings.content_height });
        if(modal.settings.content_width) modal.modal.css({ width: modal.settings.content_width });
        if(modal.settings.fitToWindow) {
            modal.settings.width = $(window).width() - 160;
            modal.settings.height = $(window).height() - 160;
        };
        center(modal.settings.top);

        $(window).bind('resize.modal', center);
        modal.modal.show();
        modal.overlay.show();

        $(modal.closeBtn).add(modal.overlay).on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            modal.close();
        });
        $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                modal.close();
                $(document).unbind('keyup');
            }
        })
    };

    modal.close = function() {
        debugger;
        modal.settings.elem.empty().append(modal.settings.content);
        modal.modal.hide();
        modal.overlay.hide();
        modal.content.empty();
        $(window).unbind('resize.modal');
    };

    function center(top) {
        if(!top || !isInt(top)) top = 130;
        var mLeft = -1 * modal.modal.width() / 2;
        modal.modal.css({
            top: top + 'px',
            left: '50%',
            marginLeft: mLeft
        });
        function isInt(n) {
           return n % 1 === 0;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Here is how the modal is opened from the controller or directive:

```
modal.open({
    content: $('#edit_story_' + story.id),
    elem: $('#edit_story_' + story.id + '_container')
});
```

I also tried running my `elem` through the compiler first like so:

```
modal.open({
    content: $compile($('#edit_story_' + story.id))($scope),
    elem: $('#edit_story_' + story.id + '_container')
});
```

That solved my initial problem, but now after a few cycles my modal contents are duplicated. I get one form stacked upon another.

Comment: Why don't u use ui-bootstrap?

Comment: Because Bootstrap isn't the solution for every problem. Sometimes you want to build something yourself instead of using a prepackaged solution.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use DOM elements in controllers. A good idea would be implement a service following this approach or to make something like this. http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/